# Xamarin Forms Camera with custom menu

Tags: ios, xamarin, camera, xamarin.forms

I'm implementing a Camera function in a Xamarin Forms project, and so far I've used the Media plugin, which works great. Now I want a bit more of control and just like the Media plugin provides a cancel menu button, I would like to add my own menu instead of the Cancel button it provides.

I've did some searching and can see others using the xlabs project, but is this the way to proceed. Make a CustomCameraRenderer or?

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've did some searching and can see others using the xlabs project, but is this the way to proceed. Make a CustomCameraRenderer or?

Yes, it is the way to proceed. Camera controls are very unique to the platforms, there is no unified APIs for all the camera functionalities that work on all the platforms.

Note that *XLabs* is the community project and not directly supported by Xamarin, i.e. it may break when we updated/make any major changes to Xamarin.Forms.

I would recommend extend the already available camera control from XLabs or roll your own

Comment: I just took a look into the source of the Moments app by @Pierce Boggan and could see the usage of AVFoundation https://github.com/pierceboggan/Moments/blob/master/Moments%20-%20XAML/Moments.iOS/Pages/CameraPage.cs. 
I guess it's just another option. My goal is to create a camera page with the "capture" button and then a menu button that allows me to navigate away from the camera.

Comment: @RasmusChristensen that's a good example, I didn't know Pierce ported it to Forms. Last time he showed me the code it was regular Xamarin.iOS app :)

Comment: So AVFoundation would be your recommendation?

Comment: Yup, you can find more about camera APIs here https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/intro_to_manual_camera_controls/

Comment: Great thanks. Also got this from Pierce Boggan on twitter https://blog.xamarin.com/how-to-display-camera-ios-avfoundation/